# TapGestureRecognizer in TextCell Binding to ViewModel Command

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following snippet for a tablesection:

```
  <TableRoot>
    <TableSection Title="First Section">
        <TextCell Text="TextCell 1">
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=MyCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{value1}"/>
        </TextCell>
        <TextCell Text="TextCell .... n">
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=MyCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{value..n}"/>
        </TextCell>            
    </TableSection>
  </TableRoot>
```

and in my viewmodel, I have the following binding:

```
    public Command MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(p => {
                // option 1
                var name = p.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine("Here we are ... " + name);
            });
        }
    }
```

when I compile, I keep getting the following error...

```
Cannot set the content of the TextCell as it doesn't have a ContentPropertyAttribute
```

Basically, when I click on the TableCell, in my function MyCommand, I want to send in the value from CommandParameter.

Any help you can provide I would appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It might be helps :

```
     <TableRoot>
    <TableSection Title="First Section">
        <TextCell Text="TextCell 1">
           <TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=MyCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{value1}"/>
           </TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
        </TextCell>
        <TextCell Text="TextCell .... n">
            <TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
                 <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=MyCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{value..n}"/>
            </TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
        </TextCell>            
    </TableSection>
  </TableRoot>
```

Comment: It might be nice to also explain why this is the solution :)

Comment: According to this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-xaml, we can add tap gesture. We can used Tapped event in TextCell but If we want to use Command then we should write Gesture Recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Gesture recognizers in a TextCell is a XAML bindable property that can takes a GestureRecognizor as its Parameter So What you need to do is something like this :

```
    <TableRoot>
<TableSection Title="First Section">
    <TextCell Text="TextCell 1">
       <TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding YourCommandBinding1}"
          CommandParameter="your_binding"/>
       </TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
    </TextCell>
    <TextCell Text="TextCell .... n">
        <TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
             <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding YourCommandBinding2}"
          CommandParameter="your_binding"/>
        </TextCell.GestureRecognizers>
    </TextCell>            
</TableSection>
```

Where "CommandParameter" is the parameter you receive in your command and "YourCommandBinding" is an ICommand property in ViewModel Something like below which can be assign a `System.Windows.Input.Command`:

```
Public ICommand YourCommandBinding {get; set;}
YourCommandBinding= new System.Windows.Input.Command(your_Function);

Private void your_Function(object obj)
{
  //Where your obj parameter is the command parameter and you can cast it to your type. 
}
```